# Correct syntax for media query

Tags: css, media-queries

I am getting a parse error on following CSS rule:

```
@media screen (max-width: 350px) {
  h2 {
  font-size:1.5em;
  }
}
```

What am i missing?

Comment: It was never an issue...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing an `and` and an `only`.

Try:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 350px) {
    h2 {
       font-size:1.5em;
    }
 }
```

Comment: `and` is sufficient...

Answer (score 1):

Just drop the `screen`:

```
@media (max-width: 350px) {
  h2 {
    font-size:1.5em;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Mr_Green thats valid +1 ...

Comment: @Mr_Green I can't find the source, but not all devices we would want to target use `screen`. If the OP needs print, I would advise: `@media print`.

Answer (score 0):

you test this example

```
@media  screen and (min-width: 321px) and (max-width:960px){
  h2 {
  font-size:1.5em;
 }

}
```